# Selenium (python) locating button relative to another div with Id

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

I need to click on the Ok button on a page (HTML code snippet hereunder). The button itself does not have an Id and its XPath changes. It can be any of the following:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/button
/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/button
/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/button
```

The only stable locator I can find in the page is the **noresultsfound** Id of the div before the div that contains the button as a child div.

I am unable to guess which Selenium locator I could use to RELIABLY click on the button.

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable ui-resizable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-describedby="noresultsfound" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" style="position: absolute; height: auto; width: 300px; top: 850px; left: 365px; display: block;">
   <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"><span id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-title">Attenzione</span><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close" style="display: none;"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span class="ui-button-text">close</span></button></div>
   <div id="noresultsfound" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: auto;">
      <p>Nessun risultato trovato</p>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
      <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset"><button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Ok</span></button></div>
      <p style="border-top: 1px solid #bcbcbc; margin-top:10px; padding-top:5px;color:#054a6c;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;font-size:0.7em;margin-bottom: 0px;">Il portale è progettato per una visualizzazione ottimale con i seguenti browser:<br>Internet Explorer (V9), Chrome (V 35.0.1916.114m) e Firefox (V28 e29)</p>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
</div>
```

My code so far is like the following:

```
try:  # things are good when the following error modal window is NOT found
  digram_notfound = DRIVER_WAIT.until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "noresultsfound"))
                )
  if digram_notfound:
                click_xpath(driver, "/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/button")       
except  TimeoutException:
  do useful stuff here
```

but as I said it fails on those pages where the XPath is different.

Is there a way of writing a locator anchored to the Id and find the button to click relative to that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset"><button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Ok</span></button></div>
```

There are many selectors you could try for this element.

```
//button[./span[@class='ui-button-text' and text()='Ok']]
//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/button
```

Comment: Thanks @arundeep. What type of selectors are those? Not XPath, right? Are they all equal in terms of "reliability"?

Comment: They're all xpaths. They use the class names so if they are unique it would be reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You may try these:

`//button[@type='button']`

[DOM Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsjZA.png)]

Comment: Thank you very much @anand. May I ask what browser are you using to inspect the source and how do you show that //button[@type='button'] in it? To fetch my XPath I usually copy the XPath to the clipboard and paste it elsewhere but it's cumbersome.

Comment: I usually use Chrome for I am used to it, but you can get it in Firefox, and Edge too. In Elements tab of chrome dev tools window, just press ctrl+f (cmd+f in case of mac) and put the path that you tried. If it exists, your element would be highlighted, and you may copy the text you typed in the `find bar' it to anywhere

Comment: Cool will try (I also use Chrome). Thanks a lot. Stay safe.

Answer (score 1):

The element you are looking for can be simply located by this XPath:

```py
"//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']//button"
```

So your code could be something like this:

```py
try:
  digram_notfound = DRIVER_WAIT.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "noresultsfound")))
  if digram_notfound:
      click_xpath(driver, "//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']//button")       
except  TimeoutException:
  #do useful stuff here
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Which begs the question from this newbie :) How do I get to build your XPath? My unstable "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/button" I got from inspecting the button with Chrome and performing a right-click Copy XPath ...

Comment: You have to learn how to make good locators. Automatically created locators are normally highly fragile and unstable.

Comment: You have to see the attributes of the element and figure out some unique combination. In this specific case the button itself has no clear unique attribute values however the parent div element has unique class name so the button you are looking for can be located based on it's direct parent element.

Comment: Thanks a lot. ill look for some good tutorial on writing good XPath locators. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have some specific suggestions for such tutorial. Just Google it